# Use an access token provided by Google APIs for a long time

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I created an app that also uses the Google Analytics API. However, I've got the following question:

When I'm asking for an Access Token I'm getting an access token that expires after 3600 seconds. I also got an refresh token that I can use to generate more access tokens later on.

Do I really need to use the refresh token to generate a working access token every hour or is there a way to have a user authenticate once and then always use the same code without going through the expiration trouble?

I want to have a cronjob, and while I know, it's easy to just use the refresh token to obtain a new one, I'm still asking if it's somehow possible to have an access token that lasts `forever`?

Otherwise I'll just refresh the token when needed.

Comment: No, it seems the flow as described is the one you are supposed to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is a middle path: You can request the Access Token new on each call rather than use the refresh token.

That simplifies things so you can have just one function to get an Access Token and use it immediately within the cron job. This eliminates needing to store the refresh otken between cron executions.